# Insert value into label in user control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, label, stackpanel

I am currently making a program that adds a User Control into a stack panel in Main Window. The User Control looks like following:

```
<Grid Name="grid" >
    <wfi:WindowsFormsHost Width="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" xmlns:wfi="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration;assembly=WindowsFormsIntegration" xmlns:winForms="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms">
        <winForms:PictureBox x:Name="pictureBox" ImageLocation="C:\Users\Thommy\Desktop\TibiaDisplay\TibiaDisplay\Image\goldcoins.gif">
        </winForms:PictureBox>
    </wfi:WindowsFormsHost>
    <Label Content="Label" Name="amountLbl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,3,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.085,0.269"/>
    <Label Content="Label" Name="totalLbl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="105,3,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

In Main Window, I have a Stack panel that loads x amount of User Controls like the one above. The values that are set in pictureBox, amountLbl and totalLbl are taken from a List called "itemList" that stores class objects with these values. The loop that creates and sets the value of the objects in the User Controls look like this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < itemList.Count; ++i)
        {
            ItemList itemListUC = new ItemList();
            itemStackPanel.Children.Add(itemListUC);

            itemListUC.amountLbl.Content = itemList[i].amount;

            itemList[i].calculateValue();
            itemListUC.totalLbl.Content = itemList[i].totalValue;
            itemListUC.pictureBox.ImageLocation = "C:/Users/Thommy/Desktop/TibiaDisplay/TibiaDisplay/Image/" + itemList[i].name + ".gif";


        }
```

The problem I am facing is that the value in the labels is only updated for the first User Control. The other labels does not show any content. This has been tested by using a click event on the User Control that collapses the specific User Control and moves the others up by one step. The new first User Control will have right and updated value. The pictureBoxes seems to work though, since they show the right pictures from start. Am I using the labels the wrong way?

The information stored in the list is correct and has been simulated carefully.

---

Going to update here below and continue to rework this project.

I made an ItemControl in the Main Window with the information I want to show; animated gif,  2 labels. Keeping the special Picture box because of the .gif animation.

```
<ItemsControl Name="newItem" Height="32" Width="400">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <wfi:WindowsFormsHost Width="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" xmlns:wfi="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration;assembly=WindowsFormsIntegration" xmlns:winForms="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms">
                    <winForms:PictureBox x:Name="pictureBox" ImageLocation="{Binding imgSource}"></winForms:PictureBox>
                </wfi:WindowsFormsHost>
                <Label Content="{Binding currentAmount}"></Label>
                <Label Content="{Binding currentTotal}"></Label>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I have in the code behind created a list that sets these values that are taken from a class:

```
public class showItem
        {
            public int currentAmount {get; set;}
            public int currentTotal {get; set;}
            public string imgSource { get; set; }
        }
```

The values I set is made in a for loop like before where I loop itemList.Count amount of times and adds more itemControls to the screen:

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemList.Count; ++i)
        {
            showItemList.Add(new showItem() { imgSource = itemList[i].address.ToString(), currentAmount = itemList[i].amount, currentTotal = itemList[i].totalValue});          
        }
```

I have gone through the watchdog and seen that the values have been set to the showItemList, but nothing is displayed. It's my first time with the bindings, so I need some guidens on this one.

Comment: Why are you using `winformsHost` just to show an image? That's what the [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image(v=vs.110).aspx) control is for.

Comment: My .gifs got animations and that was the way I found to fix the animation problem. I have been looking around a lot for solutions that does not work. Please, focus on the problem I actually have and leave the code that can be improved.

Comment: `focus on the problem I actually have` - OK. Your code is completely wrong. You need to completely delete that and start all over. Use an `ItemsControl` and proper **DataBinding** instead of manually creating UI elements in procedural code. Wrap your winformshost together with the Labels in a `UserControl` and create a DependencyProperty in it for the `PictureBox.ImageLocation`.

Comment: BTW, this is wrong: `Margin="105,3,0,0"` - Don't use the Visual Studio designer to create WPF UIs. Instead, create your XAML by hand which produces much better results.

Comment: First of all, I am working on a project for myself and do not have the knowledge, experience or time to learn the stuff you wrote. Everything is working as intended except for the labels that I mentioned and that is all I care about right now..

About the margin.. I am a web designer from the start.. I know how WYSIWYG editors do stuff. Design is the last thing to care about, so again, I beg you to help me with my labels.

Comment: @HighCore so you don't want to guide me through a solution? I find it awkward that you decided to be offensive about my coding without helping me to find a solution.

Comment: I can give you a **proper**, WPF-like solution if you want (which involves deleting all your code and starting all over). If you want a procedural, winforms-like solution (which will bring all sorts of problems due to the complexity of the WPF Visual Tree and concepts like UI Virtualization and all that).. unfortunately I can't help you.

Comment: If you are patient enough, I would definitely want the help. Currently having a GUI programming class which involves WPF. Sadly, the person having the class do not know more about WPF than I do and actually give students tasks that support the older way of coding. That means no knowledge in bindings, MVVM or anything like that.

Comment: @HighCore Updated with some new code, mate.

Comment: I'm writing an answer, I just hadn't have the time to finish it yet.

Comment: No worries, thanks for taking time!

Comment: @HighCore are you still working on some guidelines? :) Would really like some support on this.

Comment: Dude!! I completely forgot.. I'm sorry! I'll write an answer right now

Comment: Haha, no problem! I have an exam today and another one on wednesday anyway, so I am kinda busy for the time being :) But the project WILL be made, so some guidens would be awesome!

Comment: Mate. You can just say that you do not want to help me out? Still waiting though!

Comment: sorry dude, been busy like hell, and had some personal issues too. Let me put something together during the day.